# Why does the Spring Data JPA query fail when using the specified transaction manager?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a service which uses to 2 datasources - one that handles reads and one that handles modifying operations (insert, delete, update). For each datasource, I have configured a distinct transaction manager.

The default transaction manager named simply `transactionManager` handles reads, while the other one named `writeTransactionManager` handles writes.

Everything works fine for reads, but I have a `custom delete query` which simply isn't picked up by the right transaction manager.

This is my repository:

```
public interface DeviceWriteRepository extends JpaRepository<Device, String> {
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM Device d WHERE d.userId = ?1 AND d.tenantId = ?2 AND d.appId = ?3")
    void unregisterDevices(String userId, String tenantId, String appId);
}
```

Having enabled the debug and trace JPA/Hibernate logs, when I call the `unregisterDevices` devices I get the following logs:

```
Creating new transaction with name [com.my.app.repository.SoftDeleteCrudRepositoryImpl.unregisterDevice]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1270255427<open>)] for JPA transaction
Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@464a9dcc]
delete from device where user_id=? and tenant_id=? and app_id=?
delete from device where user_id=? and tenant_id=? and app_id=?
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [user1]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [someTenant]
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [someApp]
Initiating transaction commit
Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1270255427<open>)]
Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1270255427<open>)] after transaction
```

Everything is fine and if I check the database, the delete query worked, but it wasn't executed by the `writeTransactionManager`.

To force the use of my desired transaction manager, I update the `@Transactional` annotation to include the name of manager as such `@Transactional("writeTransactionManager")`, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

Moreover, if I check the logs again, I can see that unlike in my first attempt, the `writeTransactionManager` is actually picked as per the following logs with emphasis on the **first line**:

```
Creating new transaction with name [com.my.app.repository.SoftDeleteCrudRepositoryImpl.unregisterDevice]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'writeTransactionManager'
Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1868680430<open>)] for JPA transaction
Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@1c459897]
Opening JPA EntityManager
Initiating transaction rollback
Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1868680430<open>)]
Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1868680430<open>)] after transaction
```

How can this not be inside a transaction but the initial one is? Why does specifying the name of the transaction manager break the behaviour?

One more thing I'd like to mention is I have also tried using the DSL and define a different repository method like this:

```
@Transactional("writeTransactionManager")
void deleteByUserIdAndTenantIdAndAppIdAndPlatform(String userId, String tenantId, String appId, PlatformType platform);
```

When I use this method, the `writeTransactionManager` is picked up, but it first does `SELECT` query to bring in the managed entities - and surprise - the delete never happens.

Comment: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: @NajeebArif but why? there is no other transaction that encapsulates this one. You can see in the logs that a transaction has been opened specifically for this delete.

Comment: How did you configure the transaction managers and the EntityMangerFactory?

Comment: I doubt that this will work because one EntityManagerFactory can only have on TransactionManager and one Entity only one EntityManagerFactory